# How Do Set open popup And get Chacked value in another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

1. (1) Select  To book(onchange value) Then open popup is ok.
2. (2)open popup in Checked NetAmount then i want to get Total in Text
   Box.
3. (3)then  Cheked NetAmount To Display This Record in index page.

   i Want To point(2,3).

[image]
index.php

```
script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ()
{
$("#Debit_id").change(function ()
{ 
var Debit_id = document.getElementById('Debit_id').value;
if(Debit_id!="")
{
window.open("getpopup.php?Debit_id="+Debit_id,'popup','width=700,height=400,left=200,top=200,scrollbars=1');
}
});
});
</script>


Book : <select name="Debit_id" id="Debit_id">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select Book</option>
<?php 
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT AccountName,CID FROM account")or die(mysql_error());         
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
if($row1)
{ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row1['CID']; ?>"><?php echo  $row1['AccountName']; ?></option><?php 
} ?>
</select>
<br />
NetAmount Total : <input type="text" class="input" name="NetAmount" id="TotalCost">
```

popup.php

```
<?php
include("../config.php");
$Debit_id = intval($_GET['Debit_id']);
?>
<table>
<tr>
<th>SrNo</th>
<th>EntryDate</th>
<th>NetAmount</th>
</tr>
<?php 
$sql="SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE Credit_id = '".$Debit_id."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$SrNo =$row['SrNo'];
$EntryDate = $row['EntryDate'];
$NetAmount =$row['NetAmount'];
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $SrNo ?></td>
<td><?php echo $EntryDate ?></td>
<td><?php echo $NetAmount ?><input type="checkbox"  name="<?php echo $SrNo ?>" value="<?php echo $NetAmount ?>"></td>
</tr>

<?php }?>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center">
<input type="submit" value="ok" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: use AJAX/JQuery after click on check box, post the value to the index page & sum

Comment: for that you have to code & search, try Before making a wish